# What is the best way to put a Json string in a html tag?

Tags: php, javascript, json, html

What is the best way to put a json string (encoded php array) into an html tag?

```
<?php
$content = array(key1=>'value 1', key2=>'value 2');
?>
<span class="someclass" data="<?php echo(json_encode($content)); ?>">Stuff Here</span>
```

This isn't valid because when it's encoded it will contain speech marks which break the html.

If I used the php function `htmlentities` would this be enough or could there still be some characters that would break it?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would ever want to do it this way, but `htmlentities` should be enough.  Generally, before asking "would it be enough to do this and that", you should try doing it and then, if the results are not satisfactory, post the question.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just wanted to check that there wouldn't be any obscure characters that could mess it up.
The reason is that I'm creating a 'Report A Problem' module on a site which contains a lot of tables of results. I want to create a unique error code for each item in the tables. I only want to create the code when someone requests it though to reduce db queries by clicking on a cell. When they click on a cell it will send the json array of data (ids) to another php page which will then find the relevant code or create one and return it.

Comment: It's working on the site now at http://wncba.co.uk/results/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use base64 encoding, which can be easily decoded by every language you'd wish to use (like javascript):

```
<span class="someclass" data="<?php echo base64_encode (json_encode ($content)); ?>">Stuff Here</span>
```

It only uses a-z, A-Z and 0-9.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put it into a data attribute. It's easier to generate a javascript variable like

```
<script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode() ?>
</script>
```